# Leaflet Marker placement with minimum distance

Tags: leaflet, markers

I am using Leaflet and plotting huge marker. There are a lot of places where the markers overlapping each other like this (Don't confuse to see Google map layer. I am using leaflet.)

[image]

Is there any option that can show only one marker within a given radius. I am aware of Clustering Plugin. I do not need a cluster. I want to visualize the marker like Tilemill/Mapbox Studio where marker-min-distance plot markers where minimum distance between two markers can be provided. On map zoom again the marker-min-distance will be applied and more marker will be visible.